# pyppeteer command altering the size of window [bug??]

Tags: python, asynchronous, puppeteer, chromium, pyppeteer

I'm developing a program which needs the use of pyppeer to control chromium instance. I'm coming into trouble when my go back button is used, the size of the window is altered. How do I prevent this from happening?

Here is a shortened version of my code

```
import pyppeteer
import asyncio
import threading
import subprocess 
import tkinter as tk

class ThreadedInstance():
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.ThreadingCommand = lambda: subprocess.run('{}'.format(command), shell = True)
        self.Thread = threading.Thread(target = self.ThreadingCommand)
        self.Thread.start()

def createInternet():
    internet = ThreadedInstance('chromium-browser --start-fullscreeb --start-maximized --remote-debugging-port=9222 www.google.com')
    global browser
    global page
    async def main():
        browser = await pyppeteer.connect(browserURL='http://127.0.0.1:9222', autoclose=False)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())

class GUILocate():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        self.root.geometry('100x100')
        self.backwardsButton = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Back')
        self.backwardsButton.place(x=0, y=0, width = 100, height = 100)
        self.backwardsButton.config(command = lambda: asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.goBack()))
        self.root.mainloop()
    async def goBack(self):
        browser = await pyppeteer.connect(browserURL='http://127.0.0.1:9222', autoclose=False)
        pages = await browser.pages()
        currentPage = pages[0]
        await currentPage.goBack()

        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createInternet()
    locate = GUILocate()
```

[[image: Before Click][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQbcd.png)

[image: After Click]

Comment: For a short term fix I have added a line of code using await currentPage.setViewport(screenResolution).

Comment: Can you reproduce this without Tkinter?